# What's the easiest way to pull related data for a report?

Tags: reporting, related-list

I want to create a report that fetches data from a related list and outputs it alltogether.

Say, I have one custom object `crm` with the following fields:
`name`, `contacts` - where `contacts` is a related list with extra fields `type`,`street`,`zip` and`country`.

When I create a report on the custom object, it just shows the `type` field, that was connected with the initial custom object.

But I also want to display the other fields on the report.
I tried to create a custom report with relationships, but the relationship does not get displayed, just `activities` from the `crm` object.

How can I get such a list with all `name`s from `crm` plus the full related `contacts`?

Comment: So the Contact object has a lookup to the CRM object? A contact can only be associated with one CRM, but a CRM can have many Contacts?

Comment: No, it's the other way round. CRM has a lookup to Contact. A CRM can have only one contact, but a contact can have multiple crm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this by [creating](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&language=en_US) a new [Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_report_type_def.htm&language=en_US) in Setup > Create > Report Types. This would then show up as an available report type in the Report Builder for you to select. From your example, crm would be the primary object with contacts as the child. A limitation with custom report types, though, is it can traverse only 1 relationship path and (I believe) up to 5 levels. If crm were to have another related list, that data could not be included this way.

Another option, if you have Enterprise or Unlimited edition, is to use a [Joined Report](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_joined_format_overview.htm&language=en_US). Create a new report for crm, then change the format (next to Preview label) to Joined Report and click Add Report Type (top, next to Run Report) to add contacts and group by a common field.

Comment: This solution worked for my MWE, but my actual problem turned out to be a bit more complex. I posted a new question for this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/5138/817